# Replacing same needle with different strings

Tags: php, regex, replace

Is there any way to replace the same needle in string with differnet values out of a array?

Like that:

```
$string = ">>>?<<<>>>?<<<>>>?<<<";  // replacing the three occourances of "?"
                                    // values of array

echo str_multiple_replace($string, array("Hello", "World", "!"));
```

Output:

```
">>>Hallo<<<>>>World<<<>>>!<<<"
```

How can the function str_multiple_replace look like to replace the three question marks with the content of the array.

EDIT: Let content **NOT** affect the replacing, so for example, if there is a "?" in the array, it shouldn't be replaced.

Comment: Pretty sure he means needle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not exactly the same format as your example, but the concept is the same:

PHP's `printf()` produces output according to a format:

```
$string=">>>%s<<<>>>%s<<<>>>%s<<<";
$length=printf($string,"Hello", "World", "!");
```

```
Outputs: >>>Hello<<<>>>World<<<>>>!<<<
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php

Comment: Correct, but won't work as body of imagined str_multiple_replace, maybe with php.net/manual/en/function.vsprintf.php

Comment: @cske Good call. Didn't know about that one. Reflected in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18769391/replacing-same-needle-with-different-strings#answer-18769681) by anubhava.

Answer (score 2):

Use [preg_replace_callback()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
$string = ">>>?<<<>>>?<<<>>>?<<<";
$subs   = array('Hello','World','!');
echo preg_replace_callback('#\?#',function ($matches) use (&$subs) {
    return array_shift($subs);
},$string);
```

Or:

```
$string = ">>>?<<<>>>?<<<>>>?<<<";
$subs   = array('Hello','World','!');

function str_multiple_replace($string, $needle, $subs) {
  return preg_replace_callback('#'.preg_quote($needle,'#').'#',function ($matches) use (&$subs) {
    return array_shift($subs);
  },$string);
}

echo str_multiple_replace($string,'?',$subs);
```

Comment: Working version: http://codepad.viper-7.com/bqqhUl -- this is the solution I was coming here to post :) +1

Answer (score 2):

You can actually utilize [**`vprintf function`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.vprintf.php) to make this code **extremely simple**:

```
$string = ">>>?<<<%s>>>?<<<>>>?<<<";
$arr = array('Hello', 'World', '!');
vprintf(str_replace(array('%', '?'), array('%%', '%s'), $string), $subs);
```

**UPDATE: Code using vsprintf function:** (Thanks to @ComFreek)

```
function str_multiple_replace($str, $needle, $subs) {
    return vsprintf(str_replace(array('%', $needle), array('%%', '%s'), $str), $subs);
}

$string = ">>>?<<<%s>>>?<<<>>>?<<<";
echo str_multiple_replace($string, '?', array('Hello', 'World', '!'));
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
>>>Hello<<<%s>>>World<<<>>>!<<<
```

Comment: This will give wrong results if there are any printf type specifier in the input string.

Comment: @ComFreek: Good point, I corrected it and updated the example also.

Comment: +1! I've built a function around it for reusing: http://3v4l.org/CqKQl Maybe, you want to incorporate it into your answer.

Answer (score 0):

A brute force solution would be something like....

```
function str_multiple_replace($haystack, $needle, $replacements)
{
   $out = '';
   while ($haystack && count($needle)) {
      $out .= substr($haystack, 0,1);
      $haystack = substr($haystack, 1);
      if (substr($out, -1*strlen($needle)) === $needle) {
         $out = substr($out, 0, -1*strlen($needle)) . array_shift($replacements);
      }
   }
   $out .= $haystack;
   return $out;
}
```